# Mix of Forms Authentication and OAuth for Web API project doesn't return 401 in case of expired token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, forms-authentication

I'm developing `ASP.NET Web API` application which uses `OAuth` (`owin`) protocol to authenticate my clients. Some time after the initial version of the API I've added additional Forms authentication (cookie based) and mixed in `ASP.NET MVC` app on top of it. Now, during startup I

```
// forms
app.UseCookieAuthentication(... options ...);
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

// oauth
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer
```

It works perfect and my MVC users can call my API without need to be authenticated which is cool. The only drawback and it causes lots of issues now is that when my API clients are trying to access the API with an expired token instead of 401 error I'm getting 200 and html response of my login page.

```
Request:
GET https://server.com/api/v1/controller/action1
Authoration: bearer <expired token here>

Response:
200 <html>
```

What I need is that any API request with expired token should lead to 403 http response and no login page.

Is it possible to achieve in my mixed environment or should I split my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CookieAuthenticationProvider` has a handler to customize this behavior

```
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
{
     OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
     {
         // check if ctx is an API request
         if (!IsApiRequest(ctx))
         {
             ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
         }
     }
}
```